# What does `hardhat_impersonateAccount`/`hardhat_stopImpersonatingAccount ` exactly do to the given address on hardhat?

Tags: solidity, ethereumjs, hardhat

Let's say I used [hardhat_impersonateAccount](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#hardhat-impersonateaccount) method to impersonate an account and get a `Signer`:

```
const imposter = "0x364d6D0333432C3Ac016Ca832fb8594A8cE43Ca6";

await hre.network.provider.request({
  method: "hardhat_impersonateAccount",
  params: [imposter],
});

const signer = await ethers.getSigner(imposter);
```

Then stop impersonating it with [hardhat_stopImpersonatingAccount](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/reference/#hardhat-stopimpersonatingaccount) after utilizing `signer`:

```
await hre.network.provider.request({
  method: "hardhat_stopImpersonatingAccount",
  params: [imposter],
});
```

Now, how can I validate that it worked - did anything related to the `imposter` address did reset? Because the balance of the `imposter`/`signer` remains the same even after the above call.

I'm a bit unclear about what the above pair of hardhat network methods do to the given address behind the scenes. Help.